# In XCode 8, how do you use regex search replace to change the case of a character?

Tags: regex, xcode, xcode8

I inherited an Objective C project with a bunch of methods named things like "getMerchantSettings". Of course in Objective C (unlike Java) it is unconventional to use the word "get" in the method name for getters, since it makes them incompatible with auto-synthesized property getters, etc.

I can globally search my project to find all such offending method names using a regex pattern like `get([A-Z])`. In SublimeText I can replace all these with `\L$1` and it will change everything like "getMerchantSettings" to just say "merchantSettings"; the \L will make the "M" character into the lower case "m" when it replaces it.

However in XCode's version of regex, \L and \l both do not work. What is the regex replacement pattern to use in XCode 8 to make it change the case of whatever it's replacing? Would prefer not to have to use a separate text editor for things like that. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but you will either replace those letters manually, or use Notepad++/SublimeText, or write your own app in your favorite language to do that. XCode 8 regex replacement - as you yourself stated - does not support these case change operators. There are no equivalents, nor similar operators across regex flavors.

Comment: TextWrangler for MacOS has a really simple case-change option in the Text menu.

Answer (score 5):

XCode 8 can't do that for you unfortunately. As you have perl, you can open a terminal, `cd` to your repo and run this:

```
find . -name *.[EXTENSION] -exec perl -i.bak -pe 's/get([A-Z])/\L$1/' {} \;
```

This will generate a backup of your files (`.bak` files) and change your getters to the needed format.

Comment: @Hlung you need to replace `[EXTENSION]` with the correct file type

Comment: Yes. I replaced. You can try `find . *.swift`. It always return `no matches found: *.swift`.

Comment: what's the output for `find . -name *.swift`? @Hlung

Comment: ➜ find . -name *.swift
`no matches found: *.swift`

Comment: I think you need double quotes around `*.swift`.  This works: `find . -name "*.swift"`